# Tensorflow can't reconcile manually created model with the one using layers api

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

I am having trouble manually recreating a model that I created using layers API. Here are the two formulations that I believe should be equal but are not working out to be somehow when I run them.

```
def create_mlp_net(input_images=input_images, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('mlp', reuse = reuse):
        l1 = tf.layers.dense(input_images, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        y = tf.layers.dense(l2, 10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    return y

def manual_create_mlp_net(input_images=input_images, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('mlp', reuse = reuse):
        W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,512]))
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input_images,W1) + b1)
        W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512,512]))
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
        l2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l1,W2) + b2)
        W3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512,10]))
        b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
        y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(l2,W3) + b3)
    return y
```

The first one yields an accuracy of 97% while the manual one that of 11%. I can't seem to figure out why as they should be identical. Below is the minimal working code that I am using to run this.

## Correct Implementation

Based on the answer below by NPE, the initialization was the problem. The manual implementation below is the closest to using the layers API:

```
def manual_create_mlp_net(input_images=input_images, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('mlp', reuse = reuse):
        W1 = tf.get_variable('w1',shape=[784,512])
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input_images,W1) + b1)
        W2 = tf.get_variable('w2',shape=[512,512])
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512]))
        l2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l1,W2) + b2)
        W3 = tf.get_variable('w3',shape=[512,10])
        b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
        y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(l2,W3) + b3)
    return y
```

## Minimal working code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load training and eval data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
input_images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='input_images')
input_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name = 'input_labels')
y_api = create_mlp_net(input_images,reuse=False)
y_man = manual_create_mlp_net(input_images,reuse=False)

y_use = y_api  ## Changing this to y_man does not yield the same result

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=input_labels, logits=y_use))
train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for _ in range(1000):
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={input_images: batch_xs, input_labels: batch_ys})
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_use,1), tf.argmax(input_labels,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={input_images: mnist.test.images, input_labels: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: One simple thing I would do is eyeball the two TF graphs to see if they differ.

Comment: I just noticed that your correct solution now uses Xavier initializers for the biases (and not just for the weights). This is probably not an issue, but strictly speaking is different to what your `tf.layers` code does (it uses Xavier init for the weights, and zero init for the biases).

Comment: Let me try out and see which one works better, and will update accordingly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Same performance, but I have updated to maintain consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The root cause is the fact that you initialize the three weight matrices to zero.**

This doesn't work because there's no asymmetry between the neurons in a layer, and therefore no way for them to learn different things.

The recommended practice for non-linear models is to use small random initial weights. This is done in `tf.layers.dense` by delegating to `get_variable()`, which in turn defaults to [`glorot_uniform_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer).

Note that this is only done for the weights; the biases are initialized to zero just as is done in your code.

For a discussion of Xavier initializers, see 
[Why should the initialization of weights and bias be chosen around 0?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22093/why-should-the-initialization-of-weights-and-bias-be-chosen-around-0)

Comment: The tensorflow official guide follows similar pattern. Moreover, I tested this out by creating a basic net with no issues def basicnet(input_images):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(input_images,W)+b)
    return y

Comment: @ste_kwr: Could you point me to the official docs that recommend this? (I'd like to fix them: zero-initializing dense layer weights is really not a good idea). By default, `tf.layers.dense` definitely uses random uniform initializers for `W`, and your `tf.layers` code is using those defaults.

Comment: Hi, here the example does the same thing. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/mnist/beginners  However, your answer seems to have fixed the issue in my network. I will update the code above to reflect that. Somehow, that doesn't happen to be a problem in that specific example in that documentation.

Comment: @ste_kwr: Those are very old docs (TF 1.1). Is this still being recommended in the current docs?

Comment: I have not been able to find a corresponding page with a simple example in the new docs.

Comment: One question I do have is why does this work for the "basicnet" example - or that documentation? Is this because of the defined variable scope (which is not present in that example) causing the global initializer to not work?

Comment: @ste_kwr: I am not sure which code you refer to when you say *the "basicnet" example*.

Comment: The same as the one in the older documentation.  def basicnet(input_images): W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10])) b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10])) y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(input_images,W)+b) return y

Comment: The TF tutorial you mention is on linear models, which don't have problems like symmetry breaking, zero-gradient activation functions etc. that appear in deep networks. For linear models, initializing everything to 0 works. For deep networks it will fail.